# How to import PDF to indesign while preserving interactive elements?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

My company wants me to add these survey pdfs that our clients filled out in acrobat. They include checkboxes that I can't get to show up in indesign.

Here is the file when I open it in acrobat:

[image]

And here it is after I place it in indesign:

[image]

Does anyone know which setting I need to use to preserve the checkboxes when placing the pdfs in indesign?

Comment: It would appear that you merely don't have the fonts which were used in the PDF active on your system.

Comment: What happens when you write out the PDF from InDesign? It may be necessary to copy over the fields in Acrobat.